# How to delete record according to previous row condition?

Tags: sas

I am wondering if I can modify or delete records based on the value in the previous row. For example,

```
data test;
    input id seq var $ @@;
    datalines;
    1 1 Y
    1 2 .
    2 1 N
    2 2 a
;
run;
```

For each id, I would like to delete where seq = 2 if (var = 'Y' where seq = 1). For example, for id=1, if seq = 1 and var = 'Y' then delete where id=1 and seq=2.

Comment: Thanks for editing Joe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest in SQL:

```
proc sql;
  delete from test T where exists (
    select 1 from test E where E.id=T.id and E.seq=1 and E.var='Y')
    and seq=2;
quit;
```

Data step is also possible:

```
data want;
  set test;
  retain deleteme;
  if seq=1 then do;
    if var='Y' then deleteme=1;
    else deleteme=0;
  end;
  else if seq=2 and deleteme=1 then delete;
run;
```

You need to retain the value across records.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest in Data step :)

```
data output;
    set test;
    if (seq=2 and lag(seq)=1 and lag(var)='Y') then delete;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition in your data step to delete..

```
data want;
     set test;
     if(seq eq 2 and var ne "") then delete;
end;
```

The condition which you have mentioned is bit confusing where u mentioned var eq 1 and var eq 2.

So, according to your condition u can modify the above code condition.

*Note: In SAS missing values for numeric is .(dot/period). however for character variable it is blank. if u intentionally make this is as dot.. it is fine. then in the above code it will be var ne '.'.*

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the question. For each subject, I would like to delete the second record if the first record has var='Y'. its something like if (id=1 and seq=2 and var='Y') then (delete where id=1 and seq=2). but I need to do this for each subject.